# How to prevent slimes from spawning in a large area

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've made a 130 by 130 block pyramid (at the base of the pyramid) in minecraft and have already made the floor out of quartz blocks with sea lanterns here and there. I would not like to replace this floor with slabs or glass, and slimes are spawning a LOT. How can I stop them from spawning while keeping the floor decent looking and simple to walk on?

Comment: /gamerule MobSpawning false

Comment: I'm on Xbox 360.

Comment: Peaceful mode? Without mods, it's not possible

Comment: My edits are glitchy and removing parts of edits, please reject my edit reviewer

Comment: the only way to make slimes not spawn, but others spawn is to build it higher

Answer (score 1):

Slimes spawn in particular areas ("chunks") below height 40.  If you built the pyramid in one of these areas far enough down that they're spawning in the pyramid, you'll either have to change the game mode to Peaceful to prevent all monster spawns, or move/raise the pyramid.

Alternately, slimes, like many (all?) other mobs, only spawn on opaque blocks.  You could replace the pyramid floor with glass or another block that can be at least partially seen through - or just the part the slimes can spawn in.  Unfortunately, in a slime chunk, the slimes spawn regardless of light level, so simply lighting up the floor won't stop them.

Finally, if you don't have a planned use for that part of the pyramid, you could wall it off with glass and have a natural slime tank, like a zoo exhibit.  Only about 1 in 10 chunks spawn slimes naturally, so unless you're rather unfortunate and centered the pyramid around the slime chunk, they should hopefully be spawning only on one side or corner, not the majority of the floor space.  If you're adding floors inside the pyramid, the slimes will stop being an issue once you're above height 40, as well.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime